# Jest mounting component - Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, mount, enzyme, jestjs

Having trouble getting enzyme MOUNT to work for my component unit testing. I have a basic component that imports a component from an external package and I would like to do a full render so I can see the children of that external component. This is a small issue but need to get MOUNT working for other smarter components.

Current behavior:

    `Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)`

Code

```
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl'

class TestMenu extends PureComponent {
 render() {
 return (
  <div className="container">
       <FormattedMessage
           defaultMessage={'HELLO'} />
  </div>
 )
 }
}export default TestMenu



describe.only('<Test />', () => { let testMenu
    beforeEach(() => {
      testMenu = mount(<TestMenu {...props}/>)
    })
  it('Should render the Formatted Component with <span>'Hello'</span>', 
     () => {
      expect(testMenu.find('span').text()).to.equal('Hello')
 })
})
```